# React Hooks: useState with onClick only updating after the 2nd time button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

When I try to click on the button 'To/FROM selected units' the addtoproduction function is being called and data is being logged. It does not work the first time I do it however the second time it does.

I'm guessing useEffect would work because it is asynchronous, but I don't know how to write it or where to put it. Eventually this data will be posted to the back end of the server.

please help me getting this button to console log the correct values the first time it is clicked on.

Code:

```
 const [AddRemoveDatabaseChanges, setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges] = useState(null)
  const [AddRemoveDatabaseMode, setAddRemoveDatabaseMode] = useState('ADD')

 const addtoproduction =  () => {

    let databaseChanges = unitTestsData.map(tests => { 
    return {
      "unit_test_id": tests.unit_test_template_id,
      "databases": tests.databases
    }
  })
  setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(databaseChanges)

  if(AddRemoveDatabaseChanges != null && AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'ADD'){
   
    setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(databaseChanges)
   
    console.log('added data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges);

  } else if (AddRemoveDatabaseChanges != null && AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'REMOVE') {
    setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(databaseChanges)
    console.log('removed data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges )

  }
  }
```

Button:

```
   <div style={{width: '100%'}}>
          <Button 
          text='TO/FROM SELECTED UNIT TESTS'
          onClick={addtoproduction}

           />
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the state change is Async hence we should not use the state just after setting it. Instead use `useEffect` link this:-

```
  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(AddRemoveDatabaseChanges);
 }, [AddRemoveDatabaseChanges])
```

This will console the updated state and you can use the state value here to implement any logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about the button, it is calling the handler correctly, but your `addtoproduction` function should be rewritten. Set state functions are asynchronous, so you cannot use their result immediately after them. Here you call `setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges` and in the next line check for `AddRemoveDatabaseChanges` when it is not yet set into the state. As a result, it is not working as expected the first time, but the next time the state is already set and you see the console.log

Comment: Ahh thank you. So I removed that but now the data is returning null which is what I don't want and the check for addRemoveDatabaseChanges was to check for those null values. Anyway around this?

Comment: You can replace the check for AddRemoveDatabaseChanges with databaseChanges, which should hold the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve

```
const [AddRemoveDatabaseChanges, setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges] = useState(null)
  const [AddRemoveDatabaseMode, setAddRemoveDatabaseMode] = useState('ADD')

  useEffect(() => {
    if(AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'ADD'){  
      console.log('added data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges);
    } else if (AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'REMOVE') {
      console.log('removed data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges );
    }
  }, [AddRemoveDatabaseChanges, AddRemoveDatabaseMode]);

  const addtoproduction =  () => {
    let databaseChanges = unitTestsData.map(tests => { 
      return {
        "unit_test_id": tests.unit_test_template_id,
        "databases": tests.databases,
      }
    })
    setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(databaseChanges);
    setAddRemoveDatabaseMode('ADD'); // Pass ADD/REMOVE depending on your call
  }
```